# NLE journal class and BibTeX incompatibility

Tags: bibtex, document-classes, journal

I am having a hard time trying to include a working `*.bib` file in the NLE journal class that can be downloaded [here](https://mc.manuscriptcentral.com/societyimages/nle/NLE_LaTeX_Style_File.zip). The same `*.bib` file is working perfectly with the standard `article` class.

It seems that the journal class is outdated and is incompatible with BibTeX? Could you please suggest a workaround?

Below is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{nle}

\begin{document}

This is a citation \cite{Foo}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

and the `references.bib` file:

```
@ARTICLE{Foo,
  author={Foo Bar},
  title={Some title},
  year={2000}
}
```

Comment: Please add a [Minimal working example with Bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography). What `.bib` file doesn't work?

Comment: Thank you @skpblack for your reply. I have edited the question to include a MWE.

Comment: You are absolutely correct in calling the `nle` class outdated. In the package's user guide, one finds the recommendation that one should use `\documentstyle{nle}` to start off the document, even though `\documentstyle` shouldn't be used with LaTeX2e and the user guide file starts off with `\documentclass{nle}`. Stay away from this template, if at all possible.

Comment: @Mico, ideally we should contact them with an updated class. I don't have the expertise for doing it myself, but I tried contacting them. No reply so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trouble seems to be basically with `plain` *style* (and possibly others). With `alpha` style works but maybe you must use a style more suitable with the instructions given at [**nleguide**](https://gate.ac.uk/sale/hc-for-nlp-survey/NLE-survey/nleguide.pdf) as [**fullname.bst**](https://gate.ac.uk/sale/hc-for-nlp-survey/NLE-survey/fullname.bst).

Try to download [**fullname.bst**](https://gate.ac.uk/sale/hc-for-nlp-survey/NLE-survey/fullname.bst) and add

```
\bibliographystyle{fullname}
```

### MWE

This example runs well

```
\documentclass{nle}

\begin{document}

This is a citation \cite{Foo}.

\bibliographystyle{fullname}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The guide says

> #### Bibliography
>
> As with standard LaTeX, there are two ways of producing a bibliography;
>   either by compiling a list of references by hand (using a `thebibliography` environment), or by using BibTeX with a suitable
>   bibliographic database. However, contributors are encouraged to format
>   their list of references in NLE style outlined in section 4.5.2
>   below.

The `nle.cls` file has

```
%  The following code is taken from authordate.sty, by  David Rhead, of
%  the Cripps Computing Centre (February 1990), with some modifications.
%  It is intended for documents
%  that use the author-date citation system.  When used in conjunction with
%  authordate1.bst, ... , authordate4.bst, it allows citations of the
%  form \shortcite{bloggs-60} as well as the usual \cite{bloggs-60}.
```

which hints at using `\bibliographystyle{authordate1}`. If I do it and use the dummy entry you show, supplemented by `journal={Journal},` for completeness, the `.bbl` file is written out almost according to the recommendations in section 4.5.2:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[\protect\citename{Bar, }2000]{Foo}
Bar, Foo. 2000.
\newblock Some title.
\newblock {\em Journal}.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Don't worry about `\newblock`, that does nothing under normal circumstances. The best strategy is to compile with `\bibliographystyle{authordate1}` and, when the document is in its final form, replace

```
\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\bibliography{references}
```

with the contents of the produced `.bbl` file (maybe edited if something is not really compliant with the recommendations in section 4.5.2).